# Trying to install Ubuntu via USB, can't boot up. GNU GRUB opens

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, system-installation

I have successfully installed Linux Mint and Ubuntu (dual boot) with my current USB before, with the help of Rufus.

However, I can't now. It opens the GNU GRUB terminal. What am I missing? (I am not an experienced Linux/Ubuntu user)

I had Linux Mint installed on my HDD, but I needed Ubuntu for a project. So I deleted the Linux main, swap and home partition via Windows Disk Management.
I then created a bootable USB with an up-to-date Ubuntu ISO.

I am now trying to install Ubuntu into some empty space on my SSD, but I can't boot from the USB. GNU GRUB is opening every time. I have tried booting it from BIOS, the laptops own boot menu (a Lenovo) and by shift+restart->USB in Windows.

What am I doing wrong? Could there be something left on the HDD that is getting in the way?

Answer (score 0):

For me, on the grub screen, I pressed escape, which opened the grub command line and escape again which prompted me to choose from Windows bootloader, grub and EFI drive. I chose the third one and it worked

Answer (score 0):

I just simply typed in the command `exit` and then the GNU screen disappeared allowing me to install Ubuntu

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).